# Unable to Locate an element for Salesforce Lightning

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Technology:

- Salesforce
- Lightning
- Selenium webdriver

Html:

```
<a href="/lightning/o/Acq_Prospect__c/home" title="Acq Prospects" tabindex="0" draggable="false" aria-describedby="operationId-20" class="slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem" style="" xpath="1"></a>
```

Code Trials:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Acq Prospects']"));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Acq Prospect"));
```

Error:

```
Unable to find an element
```

Comment: Please share the html source or the url of page.

Comment: Hello, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and introduce yourself to that article.

Comment: Check that element is not inside any frame

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wait object to be visible. You can use the following code;

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Acq Prospects']")));
```

For more informations; [link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

**Note:** Also ensure that there is no any element that overlay your object which you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement Acq_Prospects = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.slds-context-bar__label-action.dndItem[href='/lightning/o/Acq_Prospect__c/home']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement Acq_Prospects = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem' and @href='/lightning/o/Acq_Prospect__c/home']")))
  ```